# Recursively downloading a website in Python

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I'm trying to recursively download all of the directories and files of a website starting from its root. I tried writing the code for this, but I am unsure as to how I am supposed to get Python to create the appropriate directories and files. I understand how I can use `requests` to make GET requests to sites, but I don't know how I can actually write the files needed to my system. Here's my code:

```
import os
import requests
import getpass

class Fetch:
    url=''

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        user = getpass.getuser()
        os.chdir('/home' + user)

    def download():
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
```

Comment: Why do you have to do this in python when you could use curl or wget?

Comment: What do you mean directories on a website? Are you getting a file-listing? You will need to parse the `html` response (e.g. `BeautfulSoup`) and pull out all the links. But a website is not inherently hierarchical.

Comment: Check out the [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org/) library.

Comment: @PiedPiper It's not a matter of "having to do it", I can easily do wget -r in a Unix terminal but that isn't what I want to do. I want to create a script in Python that does the equivalent of that. If I have a website and / is the directory listing, I need the script to recursively download the files in it (i.e PDFs, txts)

Comment: @Chase how about pycurl http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/?

Comment: Where is the recursion?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I cannot recursively download files if I'm unable to download a single file via Python

Comment: Then you should edit the title of your question. As for writing the files to your system, do you know how to open a file and write to it in Python? Which part of this process do you need help with?

Comment: @PiedPiper As with a small amount of Python packages I can't install it using pip or manually. Are there any other good solutions?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I can write to files. There has to be an easier way than to keep writing each file though. What if I need a directory too? And the files will be of different formats

Comment: "There has to be an easier way to keep writing each file though. " An easier way than what? If you need a directory, then create one. As for formats, there is only binary. "File format" is a contrivance of an app which consumes a file. As far as the Internet cares, everything is just a sequence of bits. There is no "format".

Comment: @Code-Apprenrice My ideal solution would be a method like wget -r where it is just using GET requests to replicate the files, but in Python code